# RDLC - IIF expression error - Argument not specified for parameter 'FalsePart'

Tags: if-statement, rdlc

I have a RDLC report with following expression:

```
=Iif(
    (Fields!EnvironmentalAuditorCompany.Value = "" and Fields!EnvironmentalAuditorPerson.Value&lt;&gt;""), 
    (Fields!EnvironmentalAuditorPerson.Value), 
        (
            Iif(Fields!EnvironmentalAuditorPerson.Value = "" and Fields!EnvironmentalAuditorCompany.Value&lt;&gt;""), 
            (Fields!EnvironmentalAuditorCompany.Value), 
            Iif(Fields!EnvironmentalAuditorPerson.Value="" and Fields!EnvironmentalAuditorCompany.Value=""), " - ", 
            (Fields!EnvironmentalAuditorPerson.Value) &amp; "," &amp; vbCr &amp; vbLf &amp; (Fields!EnvironmentalAuditorCompany.Value)
        )
    )
```

However, I am getting the below error message:

```
The Value expression for the textrun ‘EEnvAuditorPerson.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30455] Argument not specified for parameter 'FalsePart' of 'Public Function IIf(Expression As Boolean, TruePart As Object, FalsePart As Object) As Object'.
```

Please assist on this to resolve.

Below are the cases for the expression:

1. Might be a chance either one of the fields having value (`AuditPerson/AuditCompany`), if so fill the corresponding fields
2. Both of the fields will be empty, if so put `-` (Hypen)
3. Both of the fields having value, if so handle the value with comma separated in new line

Answer (score 0):

You have mess of brackets in your expression and FalsePart was indeed missing for some of the IIFs. I'm not going to attempt to understand the meaning of your expression, but simply copying it into text editor and lining up your IIFs and fixing corresponding brackets, I got this:

```
    =Iif( 
         (Fields!EnvironmentalAuditorCompany.Value = "" and Fields!EnvironmentalAuditorPerson.Value<>""), 
         (Fields!EnvironmentalAuditorPerson.Value),
         Iif(
             (Fields!EnvironmentalAuditorPerson.Value = "" and Fields!EnvironmentalAuditorCompany.Value<>""), 
             (Fields!EnvironmentalAuditorCompany.Value), 
             Iif(
                 (Fields!EnvironmentalAuditorPerson.Value="" and Fields!EnvironmentalAuditorCompany.Value=""), 
                 " - ", 
                 (Fields!EnvironmentalAuditorPerson.Value) & "," & vbCr & vbLf & (Fields!EnvironmentalAuditorCompany.Value)
             ) 
         )
     )
```